# Failing to load large dataset into h2 database

Tags: java, sql, h2

Here is the problem: At my company we have a large database that we want to perform some automated operations in it. To test that we got a small sample of that data about 6 10MB sized csv files. We want to use H2 to test the results of our program in it. H2 Seemed to work fine with our previous cvs though they were, at most, 1000 entries long. When it comes to any of our 10MB files the command

```
insert into myschema.mytable (select * from csvread('mycsvfile.csv'));
```

reports a failure because one of the registries is supposedly duplicated and offends our primary key constraints.

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE(DATETIME, LARGENUMBER, KIND)"; SQL statement:
insert into myschema.mytable (select * from csvread('src/test/resources/h2/data/mycsvfile.csv')) [23001-148] 23001/23001
```

Breaking the mycsvfile.csv into smaller pieces I was able to see that the problem starts to appear after about 10000 rows inserted(though the number varies depending on what data I used). I could however insert more than 10000 rows if I broke the file into pieces and then ran the command individually. But even if I manage to insert all that data manually I need an automated method to fill the database.

Since running the command would not give me the row that was causing the problem I guessed that the problem could be some cache in the csvread routine.

Then I created a small java program that could insert the data in the H2 database manually. No matter whether I batched the commands, closed and opened the connection for 1000 rows h2 reported that I was trying to duplicate an entry in the database.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE(DATETIME, LARGENUMBER, KIND)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO myschema.mytable VALUES ( '1997-10-06 01:00:00.0',25485116,1.600,0,18 )  [23001-148]
```

Doing a normal search for that registry using emacs I can find that the registry is not duplicated as the datetime column is unique in the whole dataset.

I cannot give that data for you to test since the company sells that information. But here is how my table definition is like.

```
create table myschema.mytable (
   datetime timestamp,
   largenumber numeric(8,0) references myschema.largenumber(largecode),
   value numeric(8,3) not null,
   flag numeric(1,0) references myschema.flag(flagcode),
   kind smallint references myschema.kind(kindcode),
   primary key (datetime, largenumber, kind)
);
```

This is how our csv looks like:

```
datetime,largenumber,value,flag,kind
1997-06-11 16:45:00.0,25485116,0.710,0,18
1997-06-11 17:00:00.0,25485116,0.000,0,18
1997-06-11 17:15:00.0,25485116,0.000,0,18
1997-06-11 17:30:00.0,25485116,0.000,0,18
```

And the java code that would fill our test database(forgive my ugly code, I got desperate :)

```
private static void insertFile(MyFile file) throws SQLException {
    int updateCount = 0;
    ResultSet rs = Csv.getInstance().read(file.toString(), null, null);
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mytestdatabase", "sa", "pass");
    rs.next();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                sb.append("'" + rs.getString(i + 1) + "'");
            else
                sb.append(rs.getString(i + 1));
            sb.append(',');
        }
        updateCount++;
        if (sb.length() > 0)
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

        stmt.execute(String.format(
                "INSERT INTO myschema.mydatabase VALUES ( %s ) ",
                sb.toString()));
        if (updateCount == 1000) {
            conn.close();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mytestdatabase", "sa", "pass");
            updateCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!conn.isClosed()) {
        conn.close();
    }
    rs.close();
}
```

I'll be glad to provide more information if requested.

EDIT

@Randy I always check if the database is clean before running the command and in my java program I have a routine to delete all data from a file that fails to be inserted.

```
 select * from myschema.mytable where largenumber  = 25485116;
 DATETIME   LARGENUMBER     VALUE   FLAG    KIND  
 (no rows, 8 ms)
```

Comment: maybe you could add some debug printout to your java code to specify the exact row that is causing failure.  then, chack the database (not the source file) for existing records.  maybe you are getting date time truncation?

Comment: Could you create the table _without_ the primary key constraint, and then run: `select datetime, largenumber, kind, count(*) from mytable group by datetime, largenumber, kind having count(*) > 1` - so you can more easily find the root cause for the problem - and then analyze those rows? By the way using one statement `create table ... as select ...` is faster than separate two statements `create table` and then `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that there is a trigger on the table that sets the timestamp to "now".  Although that would not explain why you are successful with a few rows, it would explain why the primary key is being violated.